# Is uncertainty necessarily nonzero for non-eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, error-analysis, quantum-measurements

Is uncertainty necessarily nonzero for an operator acting upon a state which is not one of its eigenfunctions?

For instance, if a wave function representing a state is not an eigenfunction of the position operator, does that imply that either $\langle x \rangle ^2$ or $\langle x^2 \rangle$ (or both) will be nonzero so that there is uncertainty in the observable when the system is in a non-eigenstate of that observable (operator)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, an observable $\hat{F}$ is perfectly determined for and only all wave functions that are eigenfunction of the operator $\hat{F}$.
$$ \hat{F} \psi = \langle \hat{F} \rangle \psi \text{.} $$

Position operator has no eigenfunctions at all:
\begin{align*}
\hat{x} \psi &=  \langle \hat{x} \rangle \psi                            \\
x       \psi &=  \langle \hat{x} \rangle \psi && \text{if $\psi \neq 0$} \\
x            &=  \langle \hat{x} \rangle
\end{align*}

The only solution would be $\psi = 0$ which isn't normaizable, i.e not a wave function.
In fact, it's not the only possible solution. A function that is equal to $0$ for all $x \neq x_0$ is an eigenfunction. In that scenario, you can think of 2 types of function:

1.
$$\psi =
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if}\qquad x \neq x_0 \\
C &\text{if}\qquad x =    x_0
\end{cases}$$

2.
$$\psi =
\begin{cases}
0 &\text{if}\qquad x \neq x_0 \\
\infty &\text{if}\qquad x =    x_0
\end{cases}$$

The first one isn't a wave function since it's not normalizable. And the second one, the well known Dirac's delta function, is not square integrable.

You could say: ''What about $\psi = \sqrt{\delta(x-x_o)}$?''
In that case, it appears to be that it is indeed square integrable. Apparently there's no problem. I don't have a concrete answer to refuse that, but I don't think $\sqrt{\infty}$ at $x_0$ has sense at all. I would say it's not even a function.

Same for momentum, it's only perfectly determined for a plane wave which isn't again, square integrable.

**Derivation:**

\begin{align*}
0
&= \sigma_{F}^2                                         \\
&= \langle (\hat{F} - \langle\hat{F}\rangle)^2\rangle   \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \psi^{*} (\hat{F} - \langle\hat{F}\rangle)^2 \psi \,d^3\mathbf{r}                                         \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \psi^{*} (\hat{F} - \langle\hat{F}\rangle) (\hat{F} - \langle\hat{F}\rangle) \psi \,d^3\mathbf{r}             \\
\end{align*}

As $\hat{F}$ is hermitian, $(\hat{F} - \langle\hat{F}\rangle)$ is also hermitian.

\begin{align*}
0
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \psi^{*} (\hat{F} - \langle\hat{F}\rangle)^{\dagger} (\hat{F} - \langle\hat{F}\rangle) \psi \,d^3\mathbf{r}             \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} (\hat{F} - \langle\hat{F}\rangle) \psi (\hat{F} - \langle\hat{F}\rangle)^{*}  \psi^{*}   \,d^3\mathbf{r}             \\
\end{align*}

Defining $\phi = (\hat{F} - \langle\hat{F}\rangle)\psi$.

\begin{align*}
0
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} \phi \phi^{*}   \,d^3\mathbf{r}             \\
&= \int_{\mathbb{R}^3} |\phi|^2   \,d^3\mathbf{r}              \\
\end{align*}

Which implies (execpt from $\phi$ being a function equal to $0 \,\forall x\neq x_0$, but I've already said what happens in that case)

\begin{align*}
0 &=  |\phi|^2                                   \\
0 &=  \phi                                           \\
0 &=  (\hat{F} - \langle\hat{F}\rangle)\psi          \\
\hat{F} \psi &= \langle \hat{F} \rangle \psi
\end{align*}

All steps are $\iff$.

Comment: I'm confused by the first equation, is $\langle \hat{F} \rangle$ meant to be average or the eigenvalue? If there is necessarily uncertainty for a non-eigenstate, how can we prove it?

Comment: Both. The mean is the eigenvalue. If you are familliar with $\sigma_{F} = 0 \iff \hat{F}\psi = \langle \hat{F} \rangle \psi$, there is nothing to prove: it's an $\iff$ statement. If you are asking me the derivation I can update it later, but bassically you use the definition for standar deviation, the fact that $\hat{F} - \langle \hat{F} \rangle$ is hermitic and you define a function $\phi = (\hat{F} - \langle \hat{F} \rangle) \psi$ which eventually you'll find it has to be equal to $0$.

Comment: Ah, I had not been introduced to that relationship before. The derivation helped too. I understand now, thank you for your help!